# How to input Matrix in tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matrix, tkinter

I want user to input matrix in tkinter GUI. When the user press "submit" then it should display the matrix entered. I know how to input matrix in normal way but don't know how to do in "tkinter".
Just tell me how to define matrix in tkinter, what to write in place of "textvariable" in Entry.

Here is my code :

```
from tkinter import *
window = Tk()
window.title("Matrix")
window.geometry("650x500+120+120")
window.configure(bg='bisque2')
window.resizable(False, False)
m1 = StringVar()

Label(window, text="Enter matrix :", font=('arial', 10, 'bold'), 
bg="bisque2").place(x=20, y=20)

x2 = 0
y2 = 0
rows, cols = (3,3)
for i in range(rows):
  for j in range(cols):

        entry = Entry(window, textvariable =  ,width=3)
        entry.place(x=60 + x2, y=50 + y2)
        x2 += 30

  y2 += 30
  x2 = 0
button= Button(window,text="Submit", bg='bisque3', width=15)
button.place(x=160,y=140)
window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an array of `StringVar()`s for this.

```
from tkinter import Tk, Label, StringVar, Button, Entry
window = Tk()
window.title("Matrix")
window.geometry("650x500+120+120")
window.configure(bg='bisque2')
window.resizable(False, False)

# empty arrays for your Entrys and StringVars
text_var = []
entries = []

# callback function to get your StringVars
def get_mat():
    matrix = []
    for i in range(rows):
        matrix.append([])
        for j in range(cols):
            matrix[i].append(text_var[i][j].get())

    print(matrix)

Label(window, text="Enter matrix :", font=('arial', 10, 'bold'), 
      bg="bisque2").place(x=20, y=20)

x2 = 0
y2 = 0
rows, cols = (3,3)
for i in range(rows):
    # append an empty list to your two arrays
    # so you can append to those later
    text_var.append([])
    entries.append([])
    for j in range(cols):
        # append your StringVar and Entry
        text_var[i].append(StringVar())
        entries[i].append(Entry(window, textvariable=text_var[i][j],width=3))
        entries[i][j].place(x=60 + x2, y=50 + y2)
        x2 += 30

    y2 += 30
    x2 = 0
button= Button(window,text="Submit", bg='bisque3', width=15, command=get_mat)
button.place(x=160,y=140)

window.mainloop()
```